# Visual Studio Code update on Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code

After starting Visual Studio Code I got message in top of window saying

> There is an available update.

and link to download. So I downloaded `code-stable-code_1.21.0-1520420608_amd64.tar.gz` file and don't have slightest idea what to do with it next.

What should I do to update it?

Answer (score 1):

Downloading the .deb would probably be easier for you, because you can just double click it to run the installer. You can get the .deb file from the Visual Studio Code [downloads page](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and clicking the .deb (Debian, Ubuntu) button.

If you already have Visual Studio Code installed I would recommend updating it through your package manager.

Running the following in a terminal should do the trick

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for info, but I unpacked this archive and execute file code in it. And it looks like it done the job.